# How to do C++ style destructors in C#?

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable, using

I've got a C# class with a `Dispose` function via `IDisposable`. It's intended to be used inside a `using` block so the expensive resource it handles can be released right away.

The problem is that a bug occurred when an exception was thrown before `Dispose` was called, and the programmer neglected to use `using` or `finally`.

In C++, I never had to worry about this. The call to a class's destructor would be automatically inserted at the end of the object's scope. The only way to avoid that happening would be to use the new operator and hold the object behind a pointer, but that required extra work for the programmer isn't something they would do by accident, like forgetting to use `using`.

Is there any way to for a `using` block to be automatically used in C#?

Many thanks.

UPDATE:

I'd like to explain why I'm not accepting the finalizer answers. Those answers are technically correct in themselves, but they are not C++ style destructors.

Here's the bug I found, reduced to the essentials...

```
try
{
    PleaseDisposeMe a = new PleaseDisposeMe();
    throw new Exception();
    a.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log(ex);
}

// This next call will throw a time-out exception unless the GC
// runs a.Dispose in time.
PleaseDisposeMe b = new PleaseDisposeMe();
```

Using `FXCop` is an excellent suggestion, but if that's my only answer, my question would have to become a plea to the C# people, or use C++. Twenty nested using statements anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any way to do this directly in the code. If this is an issue in house, there are various code analysis solutions that could catch these sort of problems. Have you looked into FxCop? I think that this will catch these situations and in all cases where IDisposable objects might be left hanging. If it is a component that people are using outside of your organization and you can't require FxCop, then documentation is really your only recourse :).

Edit: In the case of finalizers, this doesn't really guarantee when the finalization will happen. So this may be a solution for you but it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 6):

Where I work we use the following guidelines:

- Each IDisposable class **must** have a finalizer
- Whenever using an IDisposable object, it must be used inside a "using" block. The only exception is if the object is a member of another class, in which case the containing class must be IDisposable and must call the member's 'Dispose' method in its own implementation of 'Dispose'. This means 'Dispose' should never be called by the developer except for inside another 'Dispose' method, eliminating the bug described in the question.
- The code in each Finalizer must begin with a warning/error log notifying us that the finalizer has been called. This way you have an extremely good chance of spotting such bugs as described above before releasing the code, plus it might be a hint for bugs occuring in your system.

To make our lives easier, we also have a SafeDispose method in our infrastructure, which calls the the Dispose method of its argument within a try-catch block (with error logging), just in case (although Dispose methods are not supposed to throw exceptions).

See also: [Chris Lyon](http://blogs.msdn.com/clyon/archive/2004/09/23/233464.aspx)'s suggestions regarding IDisposable

Edit:
@Quarrelsome: One thing you ought to do is call GC.SuppressFinalize inside 'Dispose', so that if the object was disposed, it wouldn't be "re-disposed".

It is also usually advisable to hold a flag indicating whether the object has already been disposed or not. The follwoing pattern is usually pretty good:

```
class MyDisposable: IDisposable {
    public void Dispose() {
        lock(this) {
            if (disposed) {
                return;
            }

            disposed = true;
        }

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

        // Do actual disposing here ...
    }

    private bool disposed = false;
}
```

Of course, locking is not always necessary, but if you're not sure if your class would be used in a multi-threaded environment or not, it is advisable to keep it.

Comment: Adding finalizers to every object that implement IDisposable just so you can log when the finalizer has been called is not a good idea. Finalizers add a cost to your object (it survives an extra GC cycle) and most of the assumptions you can make about internal state aren't valid.

Comment: "Where I work we use the following guidelines: Each IDisposable class must have a finalizer..."

Change your guidelines.

Comment: I don't like having classes with finalizers hold references to other objects, even if the finalizers shouldn't run.  I would think it would be better to define a FinalizationSquawker class which will squawk if it gets finalized, and have classes which need to be disposed create a FinalizationSquawker on initialization and dispose it when they're disposed.  BTW, I'd suggest using Interlocked.Exchange for the disposed flag, rather than using a lock.

Answer (score 2):

```
~ClassName()
{
}
```

EDIT (bold):

If will get called when the object is moved out of scope and is tidied by the garbage collector **however this is not deterministic and is not guaranteed to happen at any particular time**.
This is called a Finalizer. All objects with a finaliser get put on a special finalise queue by the garbage collector where the finalise method is invoked on them (so it's technically a performance hit to declare empty finalisers).

The "accepted" dispose pattern as per the Framework Guidelines is as follows with unmanaged resources:

```
    public class DisposableFinalisableClass : IDisposable
    {
        ~DisposableFinalisableClass()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // tidy managed resources
            }

            // tidy unmanaged resources
        }
    }
```

So the above means that if someone calls Dispose the unmanaged resources are tidied. However in the case of someone forgetting to call Dispose or an exception preventing Dispose from being called the unmanaged resources will still be tidied away, only slightly later on when the GC gets its grubby mitts on it (which includes the application closing down or unexpectedly ending).

Answer (score 2):

@Quarrelsome

> If will get called when the object is moved out of scope and is tidied by the garbage collector.

This statement is misleading and how I read it incorrect: There is absolutely no guarantee when the finalizer will be called.  You are absolutely correct that billpg should implement a finalizer; however it will not be called automaticly when the object goes out of scope like he wants.  [Evidence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx), the first bullet point under *Finalize operations have the following limitations*.

In fact Microsoft gave a grant to Chris Sells to create an implementation of .NET that used reference counting instead of garbage collection [Link](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/spout/default.aspx?content=archive.htm#refCountRotor).  As it turned out there was a *considerable* performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to use a finaliser in your class and always use `using` blocks.

There isn't really a direct equivalent though, finalisers look like C destructors, but behave differently.

You're supposed to nest `using` blocks, that's why the C# code layout defaults to putting them on the same line...

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("DB con str") )
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand( con, "sql query") )
{
    //now code is indented one level
    //technically we're nested twice
}
```

When you're not using `using` you can just do what it does under the hood anyway:

```
PleaseDisposeMe a;
try
{
    a = new PleaseDisposeMe();
    throw new Exception();
}
catch (Exception ex) { Log(ex); }  
finally {    
    //this always executes, even with the exception
    a.Dispose(); 
}
```

With managed code C# is very very good at looking after its own memory, even when stuff is  poorly disposed.  If you're dealing with unmanaged resources a lot it's not so strong.

Answer (score 0):

This is no different from a programmer forgetting to use *delete* in C++, except that at least here the garbage collector will still eventually catch up with it.

And you never need to use IDisposable if the only resource you're worried about is memory.  The framework will handle that on it's own.  IDisposable is only for unmanaged resources like database connections, filestreams, sockets, and the like.

Comment: "IDisposable is only for unmanaged resources..."

What if I write a class that subscribes to an event in its constructor? I need a corresponding place where I can unsubscribe, and clients need a standard way of asking me to clean up such things. Otherwise my object may be kept alive indefinitely.

Comment: In that case, your contention is that events fall into the 'unmanaged' category.

Comment: Joel->Wrong - If you have an unmanaged object that needs or uses memory then you must be careful with you dispose pattern and your use of memory pressure.  Ignoring it will lead to either: unmanaged resource hogs memory that the gc would like or unmanaged allocation fails because GC hogs memory.

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker: In that case, you should probably make your constructor private and have it pass by reference a copy of the object under construction.  Call your constructor from a factory method that can call dispose on your object if the constructor throws (being mindful that the object may be only partially constructed).

Comment: @supercat- By that reasoning, it would seem that every method that modifies state must be made private, and be wrapped by a separate public method that catches any exceptions it throws and unwinds any partial state changes. And so why not put that handling inside the method itself, where it makes the most sense?

Comment: Also how is "passing by reference copy of the object under construction" going to help if I'm enlisting in events? The copied object will receive the events.

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker: Sorry, I misread constructor as initializer; in vb.net, derived-class initializers run between a base-level constructor and a derived-class constructor, and are allowed to hook events.  This may be fine if the objects whose events being hooked are completely contained in the class under construction; if they aren't, the only way I know of to avoid an event leak is to wrap the constructor.

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker: In vb.net, it's possible to design a class in such a way that IDisposables may be safely allocated even in field initializers, but only if the constructor is wrapped. In vb.net, if a base-class constructor creates an IDisposable and a derived-class initializer throws, the only way to deterministically take care of the base's IDisposables is to wrap the constructor.  In C#, enclosing each constructor's code within a try-catch that disposes the partially-constructed object is probably as good as one can do; this must be done in derived classes to avoid leaking base objects.

Answer (score 0):

A better design is to make this class release the expensive resource on its own, before its disposed.

For example, If its a database connection, only connect when needed and release immediately, long before the actual class gets disposed.